# Using a wildcard in a condition to match reading of a file

Tags: linux, bash, if

I have a file with patterns like:

```
house
car
mous*
```

So I would like to read these pattern's file and then do a comparaison and if the comparaison contains the patters gives me a message like these:

```
              while read -r LineExc; do
                  if [[ "${object}" == "${LineExc}" ]]; then
                     echo "find it"
                     exit 128
                     fi
             done < file.cfg
```

But when the line of pattern have a wildcard doesn't do well the comparaison. If I have the value mouseABC doesn't give me code 128. Any help please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To interpret the right hand side of `==` inside of `[[ ... ]]`, don't quote it.

```
if [[ "${object}" == ${LineExc} ]]; then
```

In fact, you don't have to quote the left hand side, either, but it doesn't change the behaviour.